# GXT problems with production mode

Tags: java, gwt, production, gxt, mode

I have problems in production mode. While developing my application I am using development mode and while testing everything is working right. When I compile my application to deploy on server there are some features that does not work. For example I have problems with some ComboBox or not all textfields save it state to database, or data is not populated to tables. It seems like not all code was compiled for production mode and I do not know why.I do not have any errors in logs on server. Probably it is some problem with cross-compilation. Of course when I switch back to development mode, everything is working.

I am using ExtGWT(GXT) with Spring.

Any one had similar problem?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

In some schenario's it happens. Especially when you work with regex it works well in hosted mode and not in compiled mode.

1) Have you debugged the values coming in the client side service layer? All the values are appearing?

2) After compilation while testing are you sure that you have latest javascript downloaded into your browser? Sometimes due to browser cache you may have old code.

Can you please try find the place where the data is exactly missing? If you are sure the problem is happening from gxt side then you can post your queries in [gxt forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/).